# Is there a way to share two internet connections simultaneously?

Tags: macos, internet-sharing

The Sharing pane of System Preferences allows one internet connection from one interface to be shared to one other interface, e.g., share your connection from Ethernet 1 to computers using Wi-Fi.

Is there a way outside of the Sharing GUI to simultaneously share two different internet connections out to two other interfaces (e.g., if A,B,C,D are interfaces: share A to B, and C to D).

Comment: Just a theory here: it's possible, I'm sure, by bridging connections A and B to make one virtual interface and bridging C and D to make another virtual interface and bridging both virtual interfaces, but it seems like a lot of work and a whole heck of theory. As far as the Sharing GUI and MacOS is concerned, I don't think it's possible. I'll do some testing and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

No - this will be hard on two levels.

1. Your default routes and network routing would be quite involved to set up the correct paths for the Mac OS to route traffic along the paths you defined as opposed to the route each network would prefer.
2. The graphical interface has no design / affordance to set up more than one route (currently)

The closest way I could see to accomplish this would be to run a second Mac OS virtually and move C and D to the virtual machine with networking set up in bridge mode. That way you would be close to just having a pair of OS with a pair of forwards in place - one per OS.

Comment: #2 was the problem I encountered. This has been open long enough that I'm coming to accept that there is no good solution with a single macOS. Your VM suggestion is interesting, even if it complicates the setup needed to do this. I'll mark this as answered if no one else chimes in soon with a magic bullet.